# Search Method for an EmployeeStore. Using HashMap

Tags: java, search, hashmap, store

I am currently making an application to store employee details such as name, id and email address.  I am doing this using a HashMap.  I am currently having difficulty with a searchByName,id and email address methods.  How would i go about writing one ?

Here is my code:

```
//Imports.
import java.util.Scanner;
//********************************************************************  
public class MainApp
{
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();

    }
    public void start()
    {
        EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
        Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));
        Store.print();
   }
}

//Imports.
import java.util.HashMap;
//********************************************************************
public class EmployeeStore 
{
    HashMap<String, Employee> map;

//Constructor.  
    public EmployeeStore()
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,Employee>();
    }
//********************************************************************
//Hashmap Methods.
//Add to the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void add(Employee employee)
    {

        map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Remove from the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void remove(String key)
    {
      //Remove the Employee by name.
        map.remove(key);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Clear the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void clear()
    {
        map.clear();
    }
    //********************************************************************
//Print the Hashmap : Employee. 
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("\n********Employee's in the Company.********");
        for (Employee employee : map.values())
        {
            System.out.println("Employee Name:\t" + employee.getEmployeeName());
            System.out.println("Employee Id:\t" + employee.getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println("E-mail:\t"+ employee.getEmployeeEmail());
        }

    }
    public Employee get(String name){
        return map.get(name);
    }


//********************************************************************  
//********************************************************************


}

//Imports:

//********************************************************************
//Employee Class.
public class Employee
{
//Variables.
    private String employeeName;
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeEmail;
//********************************************************************  
//Constructor.
    public Employee(String employeeName, int employeeId, String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
//********************************************************************
//Getters.
    public String getEmployeeEmail() {
        return employeeEmail;
    }
    public void setEmployeeEmail(String employeeEmail) {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
//********************************************************************
//toString method.
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [employeeName=" + employeeName + ", employeeId="
                + employeeId + ", employeeEmail=" + employeeEmail + "]";
    }
//********************************************************************





}
```

Comment: Can you try to narrow down the scope of your question by only posting the relevant code (you could for example remove all the commented code if it is not relevant)?

Comment: ye thats no problem.  Sorry i didnt know.  I'll edit it now.

Comment: What is your *specific* question? "Please help me with this" is not an answerable question, and we certainly won't do it for you. Best for you to try to solve this yourself, and then show us your errors. That's how you learn.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i understand that but i have been looking at this for so long and i cannot figure it out.  Im not asking for you to do it.  I just need a few pointers.

Comment: ...That's not a specific question.  Can you narrow down what you want from us?

Comment: A HashMap is optimized to allow you to access the object via its key, here the employee name String. If you aren't using it for this, but rather want to iterate through the collection and identifying an object via other properties, perhaps you don't want to use a HashMap. If you're stuck using the hashmap, then look at its api as you can extract Sets from it that you can iterate through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your EmployeeStore, you can add the various methods you mention:

1. searchByName is easy to implement because that's the key for your map, so a simple `map.get(name)` should do the trick
2. for the other 2, you have 2 options:

   - create one map for each type of search (so you will maintain 3 maps in parallel, one where the key is the name, one where the key is the email and one where the key is the id). Each map will contain the same employees. And you can implement the search like in 1.
     This is faster but uses more memory
   - loop over the values of the map (`for(Employee e : map.values()) {...}`) and check for each employee if his/her email matches the searched value

Comment: I tried the map.get(name) method and it doesnt work for me im putting something wrong in the parameters.

Comment: @Pendo826 not sure I understand your comment - if you have a line like `map.put("abc", employeeAbc);` then `map.get("abc");` will return `employeeAbc`...

Comment: Even though you didnt understand the question you answered it very well lol

Comment: @Pendo:`"Even though you didn't understand..."`: What the heck? He understood the question well and understands the underlying problems well.

Comment: @Pendo826 not sure I understand your comment.  That is what i was referring to!!!

Comment: @Pendo: don't post code in a comment. As you can see, it's unreadable. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Comment: @Pendo826 what you have just written does not even compile - it seems you don't really understand the basics of the Java syntax.

Comment: @Pendo826 The `get` function that is in your initial question is your `searchByName` method - why do you want to write a new one?

Comment: @assylias im trying to create a new HashMap for the method searchByName as you referred to using name,id and email for the keys of each hashMap

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels.  Yeah.  Thats no problem.

Comment: @Pendo826 The second solution (loop) is simpler to implement - you should go for it.

Comment: @assylias Thanks i'll do that.  Thanks for the help.